# Position at bottom without overlap

Tags: html, css

Trying to set the positing of a div to the bottom. However, there is an overlap which should not be there.

Have tried to remove the overlap by using padding, margin, height and so on, but nothing solved my problem.

I set it up in a snippet with Bootstrap so it's easier to understand the functionality.

Any ideas?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.text').hide();
 $('.expander').click(function () {
  $(this).parent().next().slideToggle(200);
 });
 $('.text').slideUp(200);
});

$(function() {
 $('.expander').click(function(){
  $(this).children('img').each(function(){
   $(this).toggle(0);
  });
 });
});
```

```css
.red { background-color: #cc1042; }
.whitetext { color: #ffffff; }
.whitelink a { color: #ffffff; }

.littpadding { padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;  }

.positionrelative {
 position: relative;
}

.close { 
 opacity: 1!important;
}

.close:focus, .close:hover {
 opacity: 1!important;
}

.clickexpander {
 position:absolute;
 bottom: 0;
}

.clickexpander img {
 max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="holder">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-1"></div>
   <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="row">
    
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 whitetext centertext positionrelative whitelink">
      <div class="littpadding red">
       <h2>Sesong</h2>
       <h3>1990,- pr år</h3>
       <a href="#/" title="Prisliste" data-target="#">
        <div class="expander clickexpander">
         <img class="open" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilned.png" alt="Open" style="display: block;">
         <img class="close" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilopp.png" alt="Close" style="display: none;">
        </div>
       </a>
       
       <div style="display:none;">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="littluft">
           <div class="lefttext littluft">
            <p>
             Befaring av hytte/fritidshus og befaringsrapport 4 ganger årlig. <br/>
             Ubegrenset antall befaringer/utrykninger ved storm/uvær. <br/><br/>
             <a href="#">Bestill.</a>
            </p>    
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 whitetext centertext positionrelative whitelink">
      <div class="littpadding red">
       <h2>Sesong</h2>
       <h3>1990,- pr år</h3>
       <a href="#/" title="Prisliste" data-target="#">
        <div class="expander clickexpander">
         <img class="open" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilned.png" alt="Open" style="display: block;">
         <img class="close" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilopp.png" alt="Close" style="display: none;">
        </div>
       </a>
       
       <div style="display:none;">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="littluft">
           <div class="lefttext littluft">
            <p>
             Befaring av hytte/fritidshus og befaringsrapport 4 ganger årlig. <br/>
             Ubegrenset antall befaringer/utrykninger ved storm/uvær. <br/><br/>
             <a href="#">Bestill.</a>
            </p>    
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 whitetext centertext positionrelative whitelink">
      <div class="littpadding red">
       <h2>Sesong</h2>
       <h3>1990,- pr år</h3>
       <a href="#/" title="Prisliste" data-target="#">
        <div class="expander clickexpander">
         <img class="open" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilned.png" alt="Open" style="display: block;">
         <img class="close" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilopp.png" alt="Close" style="display: none;">
        </div>
       </a>
       
       <div style="display:none;">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="littluft">
           <div class="lefttext littluft">
            <p>
             Befaring av hytte/fritidshus og befaringsrapport 4 ganger årlig. <br/>
             Ubegrenset antall befaringer/utrykninger ved storm/uvær. <br/><br/>
             <a href="#">Bestill.</a>
            </p>    
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 whitetext centertext positionrelative whitelink">
      <div class="littpadding red">
       <h2>Sesong</h2>
       <h3>1990,- pr år</h3>
       <a href="#/" title="Prisliste" data-target="#">
        <div class="expander clickexpander">
         <img class="open" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilned.png" alt="Open" style="display: block;">
         <img class="close" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilopp.png" alt="Close" style="display: none;">
        </div>
       </a>
       
       <div style="display:none;">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="littluft">
           <div class="lefttext littluft">
            <p>
             Befaring av hytte/fritidshus og befaringsrapport 4 ganger årlig. <br/>
             Ubegrenset antall befaringer/utrykninger ved storm/uvær. <br/><br/>
             <a href="#">Bestill.</a>
            </p>    
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: using `position: absolute` takes the div out of the flow - this is expected and hence the overlap...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only adjust bottom padding of `.littpadding`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.text').hide();
 $('.expander').click(function () {
  $(this).parent().next().slideToggle(200);
 });
 $('.text').slideUp(200);
});

$(function() {
 $('.expander').click(function(){
  $(this).children('img').each(function(){
   $(this).toggle(0);
  });
 });
});
```

```css
.red { background-color: #cc1042; }
.whitetext { color: #ffffff; }
.whitelink a { color: #ffffff; }

.littpadding { padding: 15px 15px 42px 15px;  }

.positionrelative {
 position: relative;
}

.close { 
 opacity: 1!important;
}

.close:focus, .close:hover {
 opacity: 1!important;
}

.clickexpander {
 position:absolute;
 bottom: 0;
}

.clickexpander img {
 max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="holder">
  <div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 whitetext centertext positionrelative whitelink">
        <div class="littpadding red">
          <h2>Sesong</h2>
          <h3>1990,- pr år</h3>
          <a href="#/" title="Prisliste" data-target="#">
          <div class="expander clickexpander"> <img class="open" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilned.png" alt="Open" style="display: block;"> <img class="close" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilopp.png" alt="Close" style="display: none;"> </div>
          </a>
          <div style="display:none;">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="littluft">
                  <div class="lefttext littluft">
                    <p> Befaring av hytte/fritidshus og befaringsrapport 4 ganger årlig. <br/>
                      Ubegrenset antall befaringer/utrykninger ved storm/uvær. <br/>
                      <br/>
                      <a href="#">Bestill.</a> </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 whitetext centertext positionrelative whitelink">
        <div class="littpadding red">
          <h2>Sesong</h2>
          <h3>1990,- pr år</h3>
          <a href="#/" title="Prisliste" data-target="#">
          <div class="expander clickexpander"> <img class="open" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilned.png" alt="Open" style="display: block;"> <img class="close" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilopp.png" alt="Close" style="display: none;"> </div>
          </a>
          <div style="display:none;">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="littluft">
                  <div class="lefttext littluft">
                    <p> Befaring av hytte/fritidshus og befaringsrapport 4 ganger årlig. <br/>
                      Ubegrenset antall befaringer/utrykninger ved storm/uvær. <br/>
                      <br/>
                      <a href="#">Bestill.</a> </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 whitetext centertext positionrelative whitelink">
        <div class="littpadding red">
          <h2>Sesong</h2>
          <h3>1990,- pr år</h3>
          <a href="#/" title="Prisliste" data-target="#">
          <div class="expander clickexpander"> <img class="open" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilned.png" alt="Open" style="display: block;"> <img class="close" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilopp.png" alt="Close" style="display: none;"> </div>
          </a>
          <div style="display:none;">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="littluft">
                  <div class="lefttext littluft">
                    <p> Befaring av hytte/fritidshus og befaringsrapport 4 ganger årlig. <br/>
                      Ubegrenset antall befaringer/utrykninger ved storm/uvær. <br/>
                      <br/>
                      <a href="#">Bestill.</a> </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 whitetext centertext positionrelative whitelink">
        <div class="littpadding red">
          <h2>Sesong</h2>
          <h3>1990,- pr år</h3>
          <a href="#/" title="Prisliste" data-target="#">
          <div class="expander clickexpander"> <img class="open" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilned.png" alt="Open" style="display: block;"> <img class="close" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilopp.png" alt="Close" style="display: none;"> </div>
          </a>
          <div style="display:none;">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="littluft">
                  <div class="lefttext littluft">
                    <p> Befaring av hytte/fritidshus og befaringsrapport 4 ganger årlig. <br/>
                      Ubegrenset antall befaringer/utrykninger ved storm/uvær. <br/>
                      <br/>
                      <a href="#">Bestill.</a> </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible when you extend the padding-bottom of the `.littpadding` class.
like 
`.littpadding { padding: 15px 15px 40px 15px;  }`

You could also just remove the position absolute from the arrow

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `margin-bottom` to `.littpadding h3` and `.lefttext p`. And see if that helps you, something like below :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.text').hide();
 $('.expander').click(function () {
  $(this).parent().next().slideToggle(200);
 });
 $('.text').slideUp(200);
});

$(function() {
 $('.expander').click(function(){
  $(this).children('img').each(function(){
   $(this).toggle(0);
  });
 });
});
```

```css
.red { background-color: #cc1042; }
.whitetext { color: #ffffff; }
.whitelink a { color: #ffffff; }

.littpadding { padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;  }

.littpadding h3 {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.positionrelative {
 position: relative;
}

.close { 
 opacity: 1!important;
}

.close:focus, .close:hover {
 opacity: 1!important;
}

.clickexpander {
 position:absolute;
 bottom: 0;
}

.clickexpander img {
 max-width: 50px;
}

.lefttext p {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="holder">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-1"></div>
   <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="row">
    
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 whitetext centertext positionrelative whitelink">
      <div class="littpadding red">
       <h2>Sesong</h2>
       <h3>1990,- pr år</h3>
       <a href="#/" title="Prisliste" data-target="#">
        <div class="expander clickexpander">
         <img class="open" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilned.png" alt="Open" style="display: block;">
         <img class="close" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilopp.png" alt="Close" style="display: none;">
        </div>
       </a>
       
       <div style="display:none;">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="littluft">
           <div class="lefttext littluft">
            <p>
             Befaring av hytte/fritidshus og befaringsrapport 4 ganger årlig. <br/>
             Ubegrenset antall befaringer/utrykninger ved storm/uvær. <br/><br/>
             <a href="#">Bestill.</a>
            </p>    
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 whitetext centertext positionrelative whitelink">
      <div class="littpadding red">
       <h2>Sesong</h2>
       <h3>1990,- pr år</h3>
       <a href="#/" title="Prisliste" data-target="#">
        <div class="expander clickexpander">
         <img class="open" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilned.png" alt="Open" style="display: block;">
         <img class="close" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilopp.png" alt="Close" style="display: none;">
        </div>
       </a>
       
       <div style="display:none;">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="littluft">
           <div class="lefttext littluft">
            <p>
             Befaring av hytte/fritidshus og befaringsrapport 4 ganger årlig. <br/>
             Ubegrenset antall befaringer/utrykninger ved storm/uvær. <br/><br/>
             <a href="#">Bestill.</a>
            </p>    
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 whitetext centertext positionrelative whitelink">
      <div class="littpadding red">
       <h2>Sesong</h2>
       <h3>1990,- pr år</h3>
       <a href="#/" title="Prisliste" data-target="#">
        <div class="expander clickexpander">
         <img class="open" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilned.png" alt="Open" style="display: block;">
         <img class="close" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilopp.png" alt="Close" style="display: none;">
        </div>
       </a>
       
       <div style="display:none;">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="littluft">
           <div class="lefttext littluft">
            <p>
             Befaring av hytte/fritidshus og befaringsrapport 4 ganger årlig. <br/>
             Ubegrenset antall befaringer/utrykninger ved storm/uvær. <br/><br/>
             <a href="#">Bestill.</a>
            </p>    
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 whitetext centertext positionrelative whitelink">
      <div class="littpadding red">
       <h2>Sesong</h2>
       <h3>1990,- pr år</h3>
       <a href="#/" title="Prisliste" data-target="#">
        <div class="expander clickexpander">
         <img class="open" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilned.png" alt="Open" style="display: block;">
         <img class="close" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilopp.png" alt="Close" style="display: none;">
        </div>
       </a>
       
       <div style="display:none;">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="littluft">
           <div class="lefttext littluft">
            <p>
             Befaring av hytte/fritidshus og befaringsrapport 4 ganger årlig. <br/>
             Ubegrenset antall befaringer/utrykninger ved storm/uvær. <br/><br/>
             <a href="#">Bestill.</a>
            </p>    
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you some way (y).

Answer (score 1):

add margin-bottom on your css code. [LiveOnFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vzkexLLq/)

```
.lefttext,.littpadding>h3 {
  margin-bottom:40px;
}
```